# How do I let my docker volume sync to my filesystem and allow writing from docker build

Tags: django, docker, webpack, docker-compose, docker-volume

I'm building a django app using docker. The issue I am having is that my local filesystem is not synced to the docker environment so making local changes have no effect until I rebuild.
I added a volume

```
 - ".:/app:rw"
```

which is syncing to my local filesystem but does my bundles that get built via webpack during the build don't get inserted (because they aren't in my filesystem)

My dockerfile has this

```
... setup stuff...

ENV NODE_PATH=$NVM_DIR/versions/node/v$NODE_VERSION/lib/node_modules \
    PATH=$NVM_DIR/versions/node/v$NODE_VERSION/bin:$PATH

ENV PATH=/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY package*.json /
RUN (cd / && npm install && rm -rf /tmp/*)

...pip install stuff...

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app
RUN npm run build

RUN DJANGO_MODE=build python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

So I want to sync to my local filesystem so I can make changes and have them show up immediately AND have my bundles and static assets present. The way I've been developing so far is to just comment out the app:rw line in my docker-compose.yml which allows all the assets and bundles to be present.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that ended up working for me was to assign a volume to the directory I wanted to not sync to my local environment.

```
volumes:
  - ".:/app/:rw"
  - "/app/project_folder/static_source/bundles/"
  - "/app/project_folder/bundle_tracker/"
  - "/app/project_folder/static_source/static/"
```

Arguably there's probably a better way to do this, but this solution does work. The dockerfile compiles webpack and collect static does it's job both within the container and the last 3 lines above keep my local machine from overwriting them. The downside is that I still have to figure out a better solution for live recompile of scss or javascript, but that's a job for another day.

Answer (score 0):

You can mount a local folder into your Docker image. Just use the `--mount` option at the `docker run` command. In the following example the current directory will be available in your Docker image at `/app`.

```
docker run -d \
  -it \
  --name devtest \
  --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)"/target,target=/app \
  nginx:latest
```

Reference: https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/